# Multiple Definition Error -- Arduino Library

Tags: c++, arduino

I am building a basic motor library for the Arduino. I am trying to test it using the sketch *motordrivertest.ino*, and I keep on getting a multiple definition error of my whole motor class and all of its methods. I am wondering how I can fix these errors. (I am using MAC OS X 10.9.3)

Here is my error.

```
MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp.o: In function `Motor::getSpeed()':
/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:49: multiple definition of `Motor::getSpeed()'
motordrivertest.cpp.o:/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:49: first defined here
MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp.o: In function `Motor::setSpeed(int)':
/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:33: multiple definition of `Motor::setSpeed(int)'
motordrivertest.cpp.o:/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:33: first defined here
MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp.o: In function `Motor':
/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:15: multiple definition of `Motor::Motor(char)'
motordrivertest.cpp.o:/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:15: first defined here
MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp.o: In function `Motor':
/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:15: multiple definition of `Motor::Motor(char)'
motordrivertest.cpp.o:/Users/pattyborgman/Documents/Arduino/libraries/MotorDriver/motordriver.cpp:15: first defined here
```

Here is my sketch, .h file and .cpp file.

motordrivertest.ino

```
#include "motordriver.h"
#include "motordriver.cpp"

Motor motor('a');

void setup(){}

void loop()
{
 motor.setSpeed(125);
 delay(3000);
 motor.setSpeed(-125);
 delay(3000); 
}
```

motordriver.h

```
#ifndef motordriver_h
#define motordriver_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class Motor
{
public:
    Motor(char letter);
    void setSpeed(int speed);
    int getSpeed();
private:
    int currentSpeed;
    int PWM;
    int BRK;
    int DIR;

};

#endif
```

motordriver.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "motordriver.h"

Motor::Motor(char letter)
{
        if (letter=='a') {
            int PWM = 3;
            int BRK = 9;
            int DIR = 12;
            pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(BRK, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
        } else {
            int PWM = 11;
            int BRK = 8;
            int DIR = 13;
            pinMode(PWM, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(BRK, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(DIR, OUTPUT);
        }

}

void Motor::setSpeed(int speed)
{
    currentSpeed=speed;
    if (speed >= 0) {
        analogWrite(PWM, speed);
        digitalWrite(BRK, LOW);
        digitalWrite(DIR, HIGH);
    }else {
        int _speed = -speed;
        analogWrite(PWM, _speed);
        digitalWrite(BRK, LOW);
        digitalWrite(DIR, LOW);
    }

}

int Motor::getSpeed()
{
    return currentSpeed;
}
```

Comment: same problem occurs when you accidentally put a copy of library files (.h and .cpp) with the .ino files in your Arduino project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple rule for avoiding these kinds of errors:

- Never #include a .cpp file
- If you implement functions or methods in header files, write inline in front of them (excludes templates, they are inline by default)

C(++)-Source-Code compiles into object files. For every .cpp file one object file will be generated. These files will contain the machine code for your functions/methods. Including a source file will give you the same function in more than one object file. No problem for the compiler. After the compiler ran, the linker will do its job combining all object files and static librarys to an executable. Now it finds several functions with the same name. So what should it do? It informs you about the error it encountered and exits.